# When I Add-Migration "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I checked the versions of Entity Framework and the code lines, but I couldn't find the solution.
When I enter the command (add-migration MgName) on the Package Manager Console, it throws this error.

How can I solve this? Do you have any idea?

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" - you need to check the internal exception to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I solved it. It worked when I deleted the spaces in the GUID.